# Optimize Given mySql Query

Tags: mysql

I have been going through my slow queries and doing what I can to property optimize each one.  I ran across this one, that I have been stuck on.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT pID FROM ds_products WHERE pLevel >0

id  select_type   table        type  possible_keys  key     key_len   ref   rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE        ds_products  ALL   pLevel         NULL    NULL      NULL  45939   Using where
```

I have indexed `pLevel [tinyint(1)]`, but the query is not using it and doing a full table scan.

Here is the row count of this table for each value of pLevel:

```
pLevel   count
0        34040
1        3078
2        7143
3        865
4        478
5        279
6        56
```

if I do the query for a specific value of pLevel, it does use the index:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT pID FROM ds_products WHERE pLevel =6

id  select_type  table        type   possible_keys    key              key_len  ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE       ds_products  ref    pLevel  pLevel  1      const   1265
```

I've tried pLevel>=1 and pLevel<=6... but it still does a full scan

I've tried (pLevel=1 or pLevel=2 or pLevel=3 or pLevel=4 or pLevel=5 or pLevel=6) .... but it still does a full table scan.

Comment: Can you show us your `CREATE TABLE` SQL?

Comment: What other values (and their counts) for pLevel are there outside the range 0-6?

Comment: No other values, just: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Answer (score 0):

Try using MySQL [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

```
SELECT pLevel, COUNT(*)
FROM ds_products
GROUP BY pLevel
```

**Edit:**

This MySQL documentation article may be useful to you. [How to Avoid Table Scans](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html)

Comment: That is what I used to get the row count from each value for pLevel.  What I am trying to optimize is the select query: "SELECT pID FROM ds_products WHERE pLevel >0"

Comment: @Shaw Mead - Oops. Sorry about that. See my edit for some explanation of possible reason why your key is not being used.